# Calculate $59x^{-1}\equiv 1 \pmod{63}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, inverse

How can I calculate $$59x^{-1}\equiv 1\pmod{63}?$$

I only know that $59$ is prime.

Comment: Are you sure that equation is correct? If it is, then it's too easy, as my answer suggests.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Multiply both sides by $x$.

Comment: And when all is good, try to tackle the new and different problem $60x^{-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{63}$ as well (just a suggestion).